# Running Ruby without a traditional operating system?

Tags: windows, ruby, linux, kernel, bootstrapping

In the world of Java, BEA (now Oracle) has created LiquidVM which doesn't require an OS. Likewise, there are a variety of open source projects including [SANOS](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/), [JNODE OS](http://www.jnode.org/), [Project Guest VM](http://research.sun.com/projects/dashboard.php?id=185), [JavaOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS), etc.

Is there an equivalent being created for Ruby?

Answer (score 3):

You could use JRuby on top of LiquidVM :)

But otherwise, no. Whats so wrong with a minimal linux setup?